# How to make a div extend the full width outside of a container? (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, width

http://jsfiddle.net/NRN48/ (I don't want the blue nav to extend on the left side, only the right.)

I'm trying to use the before pseudo-element to extend my navigation menu outside of the container on the right-hand-side.  By the way, I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap grid

Here's my attempt:

```
nav:after {
   background-color: #12499c;
   content: " ";
   overflow-x: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 25%;
   height: 60px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -1;
   display: inline;
```

It looks correct when viewed with my laptop, but on a widescreen -- it's not even close.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the markup. What are the CSS rules for container, how is it positioned etc. ?

Comment: Don't link to a living site. Reduce your problem to the smallest subset of code required to demonstrate your issue and then include that code in your question and/or [create a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Sorry.  Here's a live demo.  http://jsfiddle.net/NRN48/  I don't want the blue to appear on the left, only the right.

Comment: please share your html code also .